# How do I get my application to show up in the "Open in..." menu on Android/iOS (using Air)

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, air

I've been reading a bit about this, and it seems to work without issues when going native. However, using Adobe Air, should I use an ANE or is there some configuration that I should set?.

Comment: ANE is the only way to go, as far as I know.

Comment: I see, do you know of an ANE for this?. (any way to look for an ANE for a particular case?)

Comment: This is what i use in one of my projects, but it is very slow for iOS8, so it's not the most optimal solution sadly. [DeviceFileUtil](https://github.com/katopz/ane-device-file-util)